# Is there a way to increment a number starting with 00 to 01, 02 etc etc. until 9 and then incrementing normally until 60?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state const `[minutes, setMinutes] = useState('0');`
and a click event to increment the minutes from 00 to 60 (where the increment from 0 to 9 should be 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09) and then from 10 to 60 a normal increment of +1 returning to 00 after reaching the 60 minute. The initial state is a string because I call it in an input field, which the initial value is a string.

I have a styled component which is an input and I pass `<SquareInput value={minutes} />` where minutes is the state I mentioned above.

THIS IS MY INITIAL CODE:

```
  const incrementMinutes = () => {
    setMinutes((prevMinutes) => {
      // if there is nothing
      if (!prevMinutes) {
        return '00';
      } else if (+prevMinutes >= 60) {
        return '00';
      } else if (+prevMinutes >= 0 && +prevMinutes <= 9) {
        return String((0 + +prevMinutes).slice(-2) +1);
      } else {
        return String(+prevMinutes + 1);
      } 
    });
  };
```

I am trying out stuff but not sure, nothing seems working. Any clues? What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you make the state value the _number_, then pad it appropriately where it's _displayed_?

Comment: You'd probably want to work with a `number` instead, and only _display_ the padded number in the end.

Comment: mmm I am not sure what you mean, can you make an example? It is an input field and the state should be a string. Or I am wrong?

Comment: How are you displaying the value? Where are you inserting it into your view? That's where you convert the number to a (padded) string. Outside of that, just work on the numeric value and don't worry about the leading zeros.

Comment: I have a styled component   which is an input and I pass         <SquareInput value={minutes} /> which are coming from the state. from there I am stuck. Could you show an example how to achieve what you mean?

Comment: you can use https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ to achieve that.

Comment: @Nokwiw it's really [time to stop suggesting momentJS for something like simply displaying the time](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Comment: Ok i removed the value from the function because I did not use it, but I am still stuck. Is there anything that is not clear in my question? if not, do you have any example on how I can achieve what i need?

Comment: @user14749773 read the link i posted - [mcve]

Comment: Still quite lost, I hope someone can help

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense _"Is there a way to increment a number starting with 00 to 01, 02 etc etc. until 9 and then incrementing normally until 60?"_ 09 is not a valid number. You can increment a number with `number = (number + 1) % 60`, convert it to a string and [pad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) it.

Comment: Thomas, you answered the question with a comment.. does not seem that the question did not make sense to you... but I am lost how to implement it in my code, could you provide an example? what is number? the number stored in the state? which should be a string because it comes from an input field? I mean it is clear I have doubts and I am still learning. if you wanna help provide an example, answer the question. Tell me what does not make sense in my question, without assuming I understand what you say. I just want to know why my code is wrong based on what I want to achieve and what to do

Comment: I tried guessing what you're trying to do but I gave up. Answer deleted.

Comment: thanks, it has been already solved by someone else

Answer (score 0):

I think this can do the job, the 0 in front of number can be done with a check of the size of the string :P

```
setMinutes((prevMinutes) => {
      if (!prevMinutes || +prevMinutes >= 60) {
        return '00';
      } else {
        const currentMinute = "" + (+prevMinutes + 1);
        if (currentMinute.length === 1) {
           return "0" + currentMinute;
        }
        return currentMinute;
      }
```

Comment: @user14749773 I think there is a missunderstand about the fact the input is a number or a string (but anyway you are using + si it could be both so I don't see the problem to me the question is valid :P)